# DeviceSupport files for iOS13.1.2 (17A860)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13

Anybody who have installed Xcode 11 would be kind enough to upload somewhere the DeviceSupport files for iOS 13.1.2 ? Can't find the files anywhere.

There's a good place to find DeviceSupport files, but they don't have 13.1.2 : https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport

Side note, Xcode 11 requires mac os 10.14.4, which is not supported by my macbook, so basically I need to buy a new macbook to upgrade Xcode. Thanks for your help.

[edit] it seems you can use the 13.1 support files and put them in a folder named 13.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can use the 13.1 support files and put them in a folder named 13.1.2

Can find 13.1 here : https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport

[edit] reports says that you don't even need to rename the folder, 13.1 DeviceSupport file should be enough for 13.1.x devices.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need change folder name is iOS13.1.2 (17A860).
13.1 folder its enough.

1.Download it.
https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.1.zip

2.Go to folder and paste. /Applications/Xcode.app/Show package Contents/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

Restart xcode.